# PHPExcel how to set WHERE value in a query dinamically

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to extract values from my mysql db to Excel file with this query:

export.php

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT id, home, away, scorehome, scoreaway, best_bets, oddtwo, oddthree, partialht, over05ht, over05sh, over05, over15, over25, over35, over45, goal, risultato,esito, campionato FROM risultati ORDER BY best_bets");
```

It's working but now I'd like to set WHERE statement dinamically from a HTML form to my export.php file. 
I tryied in this way but it's not working:

form.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="export.php">
   <br><br>

  Corsa:
  <select name="tournaments">
    <option value="Aut-A">Austria A</option>
    <option value="Aut-B">Austria B</option>
    <option value="Bel-A">Belgio A</option>
    <option value="Bel-B">Belgio B</option>
    <option value="CoR-A">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="Cro-A">Croatia</option>
    <option value="CZE-A">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="Den-A">Denmark A</option>
    <option value="Den-B">Denmark B</option>
    <option value="Egy-A">Egypt</option>
    <option value="Fra-A">France A</option>
    <option value="Fra-B">France B</option>
    <option value="Ger-A">Germany A</option>
    <option value="Ger-B">Germany B</option>
    <option value="Ger-C">Germany C</option>

  </select>
  <br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and I put in my export.php file this code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if  (isset($_POST["tournaments"])) { 
        $tournamentsss = $_POST["tournaments"];
    }
}



...

$query = $db->query("SELECT id, home, away, scorehome, scoreaway, best_bets, oddtwo, oddthree, partialht, over05ht, over05sh, over05, over15, over25, over35, over45, goal, risultato, esito, campionato FROM risultati WHERE campionato = '$tournamentsss' ORDER BY best_bets");
```

I really don't know how to fix this code.

Thanks!

EDIT: I edited my code, it's working in this way. Thanks

Comment: what does this `test_input()` function do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After submitting your form; you can get directly the value of "tournaments" like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if  (isset($_POST["tournaments"])) { 
        $tournamentssss = $_POST["tournaments"];
    }
}
```

PS : Your  input does not allow multiple selection.

Your query can be written like this :

```
query = $db->query("SELECT id, home, away, 
                      scorehome, scoreaway, best_bets, 
                      oddtwo, oddthree, partialht, 
                      over05ht, over05sh, over05, over15, 
                      over25, over35, over45, goal, 
                      risultato, esito, campionato 
                    FROM risultati 
                    WHERE campionato = '$tournamentsss' 
                    ORDER BY best_bets");
```

Hope this can help you

Now it's correct, in your way it's not working

Comment: I made a correction in your code and it's working now! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but you should correct '".$tournamentsss."' in '$tournamentsss' because in this way it's not working, you should correct it

Comment: Ok. Thank you for this correction:)  You fixed your "bug", That was my goal :)

Comment: I understand... Thanks! :)